# Corda transactions happens between 2 node? is there a way we can do a transaction between more then 2 nodes?

Tags: corda, blockchain.info-api, corda-flow

I want to perform transaction between more then two nodes: e.g.

- Loan of 1 Million will be given by 2 payer to a issue  A, B, C will share the loan amount by 20%, 40% and 40% to a issuer D
- Flow should have happen with notary sign along with all payer and issue
- I will have 5 nodes 3 payer and 1 issue + 1 notary
  how to do this?

Comment: thanks for the reply,  was looking similar to this but how node sign the txns still not able to get it. any help on that?

Comment: @AlessandroBaffa I have those changes now, can you help me with the command to initiate a transaction? How to initiate the flow for multiple owner party?

Comment: you shoud read the documentation for this, you're asking the basics: https://docs.r3.com/en/tutorials/corda/4.9/community/overview.html

Comment: @AlessandroBaffa thank you for your time and suggestion. able to make a transaction with multiple parties. Yes my, ask we very basic as I am new to Corda. :)